# Facing problems after the latest update of Buster!

Tags: update, chromium, temperature, raspbian-buster, processor-speed

I may have described some problems in my previous question. To eliminate that problem I had to flash my sd-card with the latest buster release. After that I am frequently facing these problems,
1. While using Facebook with Chromium I am getting a lots of processor throttling(Red bars with less power symbol)
2. I found that chromeium is making a lots of processes into the task manager
3. I am getting low power signal frequently after this update.Also the temperature is spiking too.
How am I supposed to fix this problem!!

Comment: Which Pi are you using? What power supply?

Comment: Raspberry Pi 4B, 5V-2.4A

Comment: Buy the official 5.1V 3A psu https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/ What temperature is your CPU ? How much memory has your Pi4 got?

Comment: But it was working fine before the upgrade

Comment: `I found that chromeium is making a lots of processes into the task manager` - yeah, Chrome/Chromium tends to be s resource hog

Comment: A thought.  It 'might'  be that this particular update implemented more frequent power condition detection and reporting.  Resource intensive sites get the cores cranking more, more power, etc.  Youtube, gmail, facebook, amazon, and their video ads.  Couldn't have many tabs open in chrome in a pi 3B+ with such sites, without maxing memory and cores.   Next diagnostic step, new 3A power supply.  My pi4B 4G mem is maxed right now with 87 tabs open. Two of them are not responding. Near 100% core use.  cpu temp 58C with fan, new 3A PS,  no lightning bolt. recent update. Try new 3A PS first.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting low power signal frequently after this update.

An update cannot cause this. What can is overclocking, or a weak power supply.

> "What power supply?" 5V-2.4A

Get the official power supply.

> Raspberry Pi 4B

They recently [released](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1490467#p1490467) an EEPROM update for the Pi 4 which reduces power consumption by up to 0.3 amps.
Just run these commands in the terminal to install it:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1PXwrnhAXKB1hb5J6_EfPy5zLQkqnbGba' -O vl805_update_0137a8.zip
unzip vl805_update_0137a8.zip
chmod a+x vl805
sudo ./vl805 -w vl805_fw_0137ab.bin
sudo reboot now
```

Comment: can it be done with apt ?

Comment: No. apt deals with packages in linux. The EEPROM is low-level bootcode for only the Pi 4, similar to BIOS on a Windows computer.

Comment: I found the pakage from apt today. A big save. it was an eeprom-image

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I thought you were asking if an `apt update` would update the EEPROM, and no it won't. But yes, you can use `apt` to install an EEPROM-updating tool. For pothers who see this, the tool is called `rpi-eeprom`, and the images are in a separate package called `rpi-eeprom-packages`.